# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I connected to my firebase via flutter app and i also give all my required information like SHA-1, SHA-256, Bundle ID, Package Name and some gradle files in android backend. My given information is correct but still not get this issue "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured ". There is nothing that is incorrect like package name and SHA certificates.[image: ![enter image description here]. Here you can see the issue. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NtB0.png)]

I want to get the OTP from firebase and got signed in.

Comment: Do you run your app locally or from Google Play? If the latter, Google signs it with its certificate, so the fingerprints change if I'm not mistaken